# Problem in storing image in MediaStore in Android

Tags: android

I have written a block of code to insert new image to Android device Image gallery through java program, please find the code below,

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "test");
values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "test Image taken");
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
OutputStream outstream;
try {
    outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        receivedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, outstream);             
        outstream.close();
        alertDialog.showMessage("Image Stored Successfully", "Media");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Image is stored perfectly, but the problem is i could not view the image immediately. I need to switch off and turn it on the device to view the image. Can anyone plese help me to solve this problem?

Edit: Hi Aleadam, Thanks for the replay, pls check my code below

```
 m_pScanner = new MediaScannerConnection(this,
             new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                 public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                     m_pScanner.scanFile(returnUrl, null /*mimeType*/);
                 }

                 public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                     if (path.equals(returnUrl)) {
                         ImageViewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {

                             }
                         });
                         m_pScanner.disconnect();
                     }
                 }

         });
        m_pScanner.connect();
```

It not working for me, it not even connected with the MediaScanner. whether i missed out something.

Thanks
Rajapandian

Answer (score 0):

Media Scanner needs to rescan the storage in order to show the image in the Gallery.

Look for the [MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) API to make it happen.

> MediaScannerConnection provides a way for applications to pass a newly created or downloaded media file to the media scanner service. The media scanner service will read metadata from the file and add the file to the media content provider. The MediaScannerConnectionClient provides an interface for the media scanner service to return the Uri for a newly scanned file to the client of the MediaScannerConnection class.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the image to mediadb through code without invoking the mediascanner but without the absolute path of the new image the image cannot be displayed. 
You have to add

```
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, "/absolute/path/to/image.jpg");
```

Invoking the media scanner is the more complete way because the media scanner also sets the oter fields (date, with, height, .....)

warning: If you are using android before version 4.4 invoking the media scanner always starts scanning the complete device which may take some time (45 minutes on my android-4.2 tablet with 16000 photos)